# Worker not working with Samsung S10 Android 9 on background and killed app

Tags: android, background, worker

I want do a periodic process, show notifications every X min, with app closed, on background, etc.

I use worker manager, work fine on simulator Pixel 2 API 28, but on my Samsung Galaxy S10 API 28 only work when the user is using  the app ( not when app is background, closed, etc).

I read a lot about, the app is not suspend, battery charger, etc.
Mi code  when I call worker.

```
 PeriodicWorkRequest work = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(WorkerCucu.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();

   // OneTimeWorkRequest oneTimeWorkRequest= new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(WorkerCucu.class).setInitialDelay(1,TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();
    WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(work);
```

and the worker

```
public class WorkerCucu extends Worker {
    public static String TAG = "WorkerCucu";
    Context ctx;

    public WorkerCucu(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
         super(context, workerParams);
        Log.d(TAG, "On constructor");
        this.ctx=context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
       // OneTimeWorkRequest oneTimeWorkRequest= new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(WorkerCucu.class).setInitialDelay(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();
        //WorkManager.getInstance(ctx).enqueue(oneTimeWorkRequest);
        Log.d(TAG, "On dowork");
        if(ctx!=null) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences("CUCU", ctx.MODE_PRIVATE);
            prefs.edit().putLong("lastcucu",new Date().getTime()).apply();
            prefs.edit().commit();
            showNotification(ctx);

        }
        return Result.success();

    }
    public void showNotification(Context context){
        Log.d("onReceive", "ladskjflsakjdflskjdflskjdfslkjdflasdf");
      //  Toast.makeText(context, "OnReceive alarm test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        SharedPreferences preferences =context.getSharedPreferences("cucu",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "channel_1")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ajustes_ima_cucu)
                .setContentTitle("Bible Cucu")
                .setContentText("Tu versiculo a cada momento")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        Intent intentMain=new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intentMain.putExtra("inicia_cucu", true);


        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentMain, 0);

        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


        NotificationManagerCompat not=NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        not.notify(1231,builder.build());
    }
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you found a solution?  I am facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found a solution. Make sure you sign the apk whilst building. Otherwise, the app is forcefully stopped when removed from Recents